# How do I build all Azure WebJobs with one task in the VSTS build definition?

Tags: azure, build, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-webjobs

My team currently has a build definition in VSTS that handles our continuous build process.

The application is running on .NET Core 1.1.1.

After additional features have been added, the number of WebJobs have increased. Our current build definition requires a separate task to handle every WebJob.

Is there any way to create a single task to hold all our WebJobs?

The image shows our current build tasks in VSTS.

[image: Build Definition for VSTS]

The settings for the individual WebJob task is seen here:

[image: Task Settings]

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: Not yet. We are looking into doing it programmatically or switching to using Azure Functions.

Comment: Using PowerShell is the easy way to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programming (e.g. PowerShell), then just add PowerShell task for webjobs.

On the other hand, you may custom build task to do it programmatically.